# enter two percentage give me the third

Tags: javascript

i have 3 input filed

i want to enter two input the third pull be putted automatically

```
<input id='cpercentage' name='first'>
<input id='epercentage' name='second'>
<input id='mpercentage' name='third'>
```

i enter in the first 20% in the second 30%

in the third it will automatically appear 50% the rest of 100%

(20%+30%)-100%=50%
how to do that in javascript?

i tried this but it dosn't work

$(function(){

```
$('#cpercentage').on('input', function() {
  calculate();
});
$('#epercentage').on('input', function() {
 calculate();
});
function calculate(){
    var pPos = parseInt($('#cpercentage').val()); 
    var pEarned = parseInt($('#epercentage').val());
    var perc="";
    if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
        perc=" ";
       }else{
       perc = (100-(pEarned+pPos)).toFixed(3);
       }

    $('#mpercentage').val(perc);
}
```

});

Comment: Try with a correct event. You can do it on change, on focus out, ... I prefer on change, since you will see the value in real time

Comment: example plz in what you mean

Comment: @mohamadmohamad in the html, add the 'onChange="call_to_function"' field in the tag of the input boxes

Comment: Done, and check you math ;)

Comment: @mohamadmohamad something like `<input id='cpercentage' name='first' onchange="calculate()">`

Comment: @HolyDanna, I would suggest you to use addEventListener or Jquery.on to bind event to function, onXXXX is the old way ;)

Comment: @AxelH I'm one of the old school, that's why I do use the onXX events in the html ><. I'll try to think of the addEventListener more, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set the event to `change`

```
$('#cpercentage').on('change', function() {
```

also your calculation was wrong at one point

```
perc = (100- (pEarned+pPos)).toFixed(3);
```

to add an % to the result of the calculation you just need to do this:

```
$('#mpercentage').val(perc+"%");
```

Combined it would be like this:

```js
    $('#cpercentage').on('change', function() {
      calculate();
    });
    $('#epercentage').on('change', function() {
     calculate();
    });
    function calculate(){
        var pPos = parseInt($('#cpercentage').val()); 
        var pEarned = parseInt($('#epercentage').val());
        var perc="";
        if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
            perc=" ";
           }else{
           perc = (100- (pEarned+pPos)).toFixed(3);
           }

        $('#mpercentage').val(perc+"%");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='cpercentage' name='first'>
<input id='epercentage' name='second'>
<input id='mpercentage' name='third'>
```

---

To get this to work with select you just need to change the tags correctly:

```js
    $('#cpercentage').on('change', function() {
      calculate();
    });
    $('#epercentage').on('change', function() {
     calculate();
    });
    function calculate(){
        var pPos = parseInt($('#cpercentage').val()); 
        var pEarned = parseInt($('#epercentage').val());
        var perc="";
        if(isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)){
            perc=" ";
           }else{
           perc = (100- (pEarned+pPos)).toFixed(3);
           }

        $('#mpercentage').val(perc+"%");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='cpercentage' name='first'>
<option>10%</option>
<option>15%</option>
<option>30%</option>
</select>
<select id='epercentage' name='second'>
<option>10%</option>
<option>15%</option>
<option>30%</option>
</select>
<input id='mpercentage' name='third'>
```

Comment: thank you it's work but if i change the input filed to a select filed in html it stop to working how to solve this?

Comment: If i understood you right you are asking how to do the calculation if the two first fields would be <select>.  
You just change the tag and add options:  
`
    <select id='cpercentage' name='first'>  
    <option>10%</option>  
    <option>15%</option>  
   </select>  
`
You can leave the result field as <input>.  
If you now select certain values it should still calculate.

Comment: Yeah i accidently replied too early. Check the edit above.

Comment: Check the edit out. Maybe you got something wrong in your code.

Comment: we can't put the third as select in html or not ?

Comment: Not really. Select tags require options. If you want to make the last text field so it's not editable by the user you can just give it the `readonly` property:  
`<input type="text" id='mpercentage' name='third' readonly>`

Comment: thank you for your time best answer and thank you for all who put an answer

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks:

- You're not using the correct event. The `select` event fires when you highlight text.
- `perc = (100 - (pEarned + pPos)).toFixed(3);`

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should listen other event like `keyup`,`change` to `select`
2. Then, maybe you want to get the absoulte value, use `Math.abs()` to `toFixed()`

Here are the codes:

```
$(function() {

    $('#cpercentage').on('keyup', function() {
        calculate();
    });
    $('#epercentage').on('change', function() {
        calculate();
    });

    function calculate() {
        var pPos = parseInt($('#cpercentage').val());
        var pEarned = parseInt($('#epercentage').val());
        var perc = "";
        if (isNaN(pPos) || isNaN(pEarned)) {
            perc = " ";
        } else {
            perc = Math.abs((pEarned + pPos) - 100);
        }

        $('#mpercentage').val(perc + '%');
    }

});
```

There is a little difference between `change` and `keyup`, you can choose whatever your want.